# Edge renders CSS transform differently every time

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I've a checkbox tick that's rendered using `transform` property. This is how it looks:

```
.ex-checkbox-image-tick {
//1rem = 16px
     border-radius: 0.15rem;
     border: 0.15rem solid transparent;
     border-right-color: $ex-white;
     border-bottom-color: $ex-white;
     width: 0.45rem;
     height: 0.65rem;
     transform: rotateZ(45deg);
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then I put my HTML on the website several times. It's the same component with the same style applied:

[image: edge checkbox tick]

As you can see, every checkbox tick is rendered in a slightly different way. How to fix this issue? Or I have to live with it because it's Edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable 3D rendering, which utilizes the graphics card to hardware accelerate your CSS.

To do this, change the line...

`transform: rotateZ(45deg);`

into...

`transform: translateZ(0) rotateZ(45deg);`

This should trick the browser into triggering GPU acceleration which might fix your problem.